# Is it possible to test spam clicking submit button using Capybara in Rails?

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, capybara

I'm working on a large repo, and we have a bug that causes multiple accounts to be created when the form's submit button is spam clicked.

Is there any way to automate spam clicking using Capybara? I've already tried the following but neither of them work, as only one account gets created.

```
find(".submit-button").click.click
```

```
 find('.submit-button-container .healthie-button.primary-button').tap do |b|
        b.click
        sleep 0.1
        b.click
 end
```

Comment: Are you running your tests with a JS enabled driver? If you're just running with rack_test then you have no chance of multiple requests being processed in parallel.  What server are you using to run your app under test? Is it configured to allow multiple threads in parallel? For the behavior to happen your system under test will need to be able to process multiple requests at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

Execute script is a Capybara method for running JS in your tests. I think this would most likely imitate user behavior.

```
20.times do
  page.execute_script("$('.submit-button').click()")
end
```